# WA in scubadiv spoj (top down dp)

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am stuck on [this question](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SCUBADIV/) getting WA.

I have seen many bottom up implementations of this question. My top-down implementation is not working with memoization and is working fine without it. How can i correct it ??

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>

#define INF 0x7FFFFFFF

using namespace std;

int o,n,num,ox[2000],nt[2000],wt[2000];
int dp[2000][2000];

int dive(int index,int oxygen,int nitrogen,int weight) {
    if(dp[oxygen][nitrogen]!=-1) return dp[oxygen][nitrogen];
    int &ret=dp[oxygen][nitrogen];
    if(oxygen>=o&&nitrogen>=n) {
        ret=weight; 
        return ret;
    }
    if(index==num) {
        ret=INF;
        return ret;
    }
    ret= min(dive(index+1,oxygen+ox[index],nitrogen+nt[index],weight+wt[index]),dive(index+1,oxygen,nitrogen,weight));  
    return ret;
}

main() {
    int c;
    scanf("%d",&c);
    while(c--) {
        memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
        scanf("%d%d",&o,&n);
        scanf("%d",&num);
        for(int i=0;i<num;++i) {
            scanf("%d%d%d",&ox[i],&nt[i],&wt[i]);
        }
        printf("%d\n",dive(0,0,0,0));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this test:

```
1
21 79
5
1 1 800
1 1 800
1 1 800
1 1 800
17 75 800
```

It seems to me the correct answer for it should be `800 * 5 = 4000` right? Your program outputs [something else](http://ideone.com/mlUYkp).

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback . I guess my memoization technique is wrong because when I comment " if(dp[oxygen][nitrogen]!=-1) return dp[oxygen][nitrogen];" then I seem to get the correct answer . Any help regarding memoization ??

Comment: Your memoization technique is correct. You have a problem with the dp. A state is not only defined by the amount of nitrogen and oxygen but also by the weight accumulated so far. you may get to the same situation with two different weights

Comment: You don't need weight to be passed in the recursion. Remove it from the arguments list and keep it as local variable on each iteration

Comment: Do you mean that I should use a 3D array ? I am new to dynamic programming . Can you please provide some pseudocode as to how to implement it ? @Ivaylo

Comment: @user3108270 yes I can provide pseudo code and I can provide full solution, but I will not as this is a very important part of the exercise. I will give you a few more tips, though: as a rule of thumb anything you pass as argument to dp and may change when you make recursive call should be a dimension in your array. However you don't need to pass weight as it is not related to the solution of the subproblem. In this case you should make **index** a new dimension and remove weight from the recursion parameters(as stated above replace it with local variable in the function).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help . I seem to got your point and is getting correct answer with the increased dimension. But I have one last doubt. I have taken a 3D array dp[22][80][1001], but the weights of accumulated oxygen and nitrogen may exceed 21 and 79 , so i am chopping them to 21 and 79 when they exceed. Do u think it's the right approach?? I am getting correct answer for your case but WA on spoj .

Answer (score 0):

This gives wrong answer too :( could someone check pls

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int swap( int &a,int &b)
    {
       int temp=a;
       a=b;
       b=temp;
    }
    int min(int a, int b)
    {
    if(a<b)return a;else return b;
    }
    int max(int a,int b) 
    {
    if(a>b)return a;else return b;
    }
    int minweight(int ans[][22][80],int arr[][3],int n,int oxy,int nit)
    {
     int prev=0,curr=1;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {

        for(int j=0;j<=21;j++)
            for(int k=0;k<=79;k++)
                ans[curr][j][k]=min( ans[prev][j][k], arr[i][2]+ans[prev][max(0,j-arr[i][0])][max(0,k-arr[i][1])]);
        swap(curr,prev);
}


        return ans[n&1][oxy][nit];
    }
   int main()
   {
    int cases;
    cin>>cases;

    while(cases--)
    {
        int oxy,nit;
        cin>>oxy>>nit;
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int arr[n+1][3];
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i][0]>>arr[i][1]>>arr[i][2];
        }   
        int ans[2][22][80];

            for(int j=0;j<oxy+1;j++)
                for(int k=0;k<nit+1;k++)
                    ans[0][j][k]=9999;
            ans[0][0][0]=0;

        cout<<minweight(ans,arr,n,oxy,nit);
    }
```

}